# Can filters hide invisibly?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm very new to Tableau, just creating my third very simple Viz.    By adding and deleting filters,  I seem to have managed to create an invisible filter and I don't know how to get rid of it.  I deleted the dashboard and all sheets but the filter persists somewhere.

In the data-source tab,  when I describe the "mix" field it has 6 discrete values as it should.  When I look at the table I can see 6 discrete values.   But NOW when I create a brand new first sheet and don't do anything else but look at "describe" for "mix" in the list of fields, "mix" only has one value.   If I drag it to the screen it shows up with that one value.

Any ideas where I might find this hidden filter?

Thank you.

Comment: could you please share a screen of the editor once you creaeat a brand new worksheet? maybe a screen of the data-source pane would help as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha.  I hadn't realized that making an extract of the source data (so that I could put the Viz up publicly) was silently filtered by the filters in place on a screen.

So, unknown to me,  my source-data had become "pre-filtered" and of course nothing I could do at a screen level after that could remove that filtering.

Comment: very well, this will definitely help others